# How do I create a smtplib code that sends an 'Item in stock' email to a specific email address?

Tags: python, selenium, smtplib

Using selenium I have a code that determines if an item is 'in stock' or 'out of stock'. The code can detect once an 'out of stock' item becomes 'in stock'. Using smtplib, I'd like an email to be sent from the following email address:

example1@hotmail.com
password: 1234

to:

example2@hotmail.com

notifying the individual once an item is 'in stock'.

What would a complete python code for this look like?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like :

1. For Sending Plain Text Emails

   ```
   import smtplib, ssl
   from email.mime.text import MIMEText

   port = 587  # For starttls
   smtp_server = "smtp.office365.com"

   sender_email = "the_sender_email_address"            # example1@hotmail.om
   password = "the_sender_email_address_password"       # 1234


   receiver_email = "the_receiver_email_address"        # example2@hotmail.com

   message = MIMEText("Hurry up.. Item in Stock Again") # Your message
   message['Subject'] = "Item in Stock Again"           # Email Subject 
   message['From'] = sender_email
   message['To'] = receiver_email


   context = ssl.create_default_context()
   with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
       server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
       server.starttls(context=context)
       server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
       server.login(sender_email, password)
       server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
   ```
2. Including Some HTML Content

   ```
    import smtplib, ssl
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


    port = 587  # For starttls
    smtp_server = "smtp.office365.com"

    sender_email = "sender_email"
    password = "sender_email_password"

    receiver_email = "receiver_email"


    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = "multipart test"
    message["From"] = sender_email
    message["To"] = receiver_email

    # Create the plain-text and HTML version of your message
    text = """\
    Hurry Up"""
    html = """\
    <html>
        <body>
          <p>
             <a href="http://www.realpython.com">Item</a> 
                 is in stock again.
          </p>
         </body>
    </html>
    """

    # Turn these into plain/html MIMEText objects
    part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

    # Add HTML/plain-text parts to MIMEMultipart message
    # The email client will try to render the last part first
    message.attach(part1)
    message.attach(part2)

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
       server.starttls(context=context)
       server.login(sender_email, password)
       server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
   ```
3. Adding Attachments Using the email Module

   ```
   import email, smtplib, ssl

   from email import encoders
   from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
   from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
   from email.mime.text import MIMEText


   port = 587  # For starttls
   smtp_server = "smtp.office365.com"

   sender_email = "sender_email_address"
   password = "sender_email_password"

   receiver_email = "receiver_email_address"



   subject = "Item in Stock "
   body = "email with attachment"

   # Create a multipart message and set headers
   message = MIMEMultipart()
   message["From"] = sender_email
   message["To"] = receiver_email
   message["Subject"] = subject
   message["Bcc"] = receiver_email  # Recommended for bul mails

   # Add body to email
   message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

   filename = "some_document.pdf"        # In same directory as the script

   # Open PDF file in binary mode
   with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
       # Add file as application/octet-stream
       # Email client can usually download this automatically as attachment
       part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
       part.set_payload(attachment.read())

   # Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email    
   encoders.encode_base64(part)

   # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
   part.add_header(
       "Content-Disposition",
       f"attachment; filename= {filename}",)

   # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
   message.attach(part)
   text = message.as_string()

   # Log in to server using secure context and send email
   context = ssl.create_default_context()
   with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
       server.starttls(context=context)
       server.login(sender_email, password)
       server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, text)
   ```

**NOTE** : While the code examples above will work, keep in mind it's old code and isn't the best code you can write to send emails using python `smtplib`, `email`.
You should be using the new `EmailMessage/EmailPolicy` API (introduced in python 3.6).
You can find more examples here on python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html#module-email).

Comment: Gmail sample here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/j-agrawal/coding/blob/master/send_mail.ipynb

Comment: Thank you for the code. How can I prevent the email from arriving in the junk folder?.

Comment: I posted a follow up question if you would like to try:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075619/how-can-i-adjust-this-smtplib-code-so-i-could-include-a-document-to-the-email

Comment: I tested it out and the emails are arriving in the inbox folder for me, so i can't figure out why its in the junk folder for you

Comment: sure .. i updated the answer