# How do I tell selenium to add to basket if item is 'in stock'?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code that prints 'in stock' if the item is in stock:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options=Options()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    
#Directing to site
driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nintendo-Switch-OLED-Model-Neon/dp/B098TNW7NM/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=Nintendo+Switch&qid=1651147043&sr=8-3");
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/span/form/div[3]/span[1]/span/input"))).click()



condition= print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='availability']//span[contains(text(),'In stock.')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
if condition == 'In stock.':
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[14]/div[1]/span/span/span/input"))).click()

else:
    pass
```

How do I tell selenium to 'add to basket' if the item is 'in stock'?

I want to:

1. go to this url: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nintendo-Switch-OLED-Model-Neon/dp/B098TNW7NM/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=Nintendo+Switch&qid=1651147043&sr=8-3
2. check if the text on the right side says 'In stock.'.
3. If it is in stock, I'd like to add it to basket.

I got the xpath by going inspect->copy->copy full x path.

Comment: I don't see this xpath `/html/body/div[2]/span/form/div[3]/span[1]/span/input` in the HTML-DOM, which element you are trying to click on that page?

Comment: When I go onto the website I get a window asking me if I want to 'accept cookies'. It is possible that you do not get this window so you could ignore that click.

Comment: The click is to 'accept cookies'.

Comment: I am not finding this xpath `//div[@id='availability']//span[contains(text(),'In stock.')]` as well, Can you update us with the manual steps that you want to automate?

Comment: I have now added more information above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ideally use relative XPath.

We are using `presence_of_all_elements_located` which will return a `list of web elements` if found, if not then it will be `an empty list`, so `in_stock`  is a list of web elements. Now, `len()` is a method that will give us the output of how many web elements are present in the list. therefore, the logic is something like, if the list has anything then it must be `In stock` -> Now `add to basket`, else it must be `<0` or `0` in that case `"In stock"`  won't be present and we won't add anything to our basket.

The code below goes to the URL, look for `"In stock"` **text** if it is present then `"Add to basket"` if not simply `tear down` the `bot`.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nintendo-Switch-OLED-Model-Neon/dp/B098TNW7NM/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=Nintendo+Switch&qid=1651147043&sr=8-3")
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/span/form/div[3]/span[1]/span/input"))).click()
    print("clicked on accept cookies successfully")
except:
    pass

in_stock = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='availability']//span[contains(text(),' In stock. ')]")))
try:
    if len(in_stock) > 0:
        print("In stock must be present.")
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#add-to-cart-button"))).click()
        print("Clicked on add to cart button")
    else:
        print("In stock must be not present")
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. If it is not too much to ask, could you please explain what some of the lines means. If len(in stock)> 0 does that mean the item is not in stock?. but then you click add to basket. else you click it is not in stock?. I think I got the first part wrong here.

Comment: See above, Updated with the explanation!

Comment: Very detailed explanation. Thank you for clarifying. How are you with smtplib by any chance?. I had posted a question here regarding it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72036762/how-do-i-create-an-email-to-say-item-in-stock-to-a-specific-email-address

Comment: Sorry mate, not much familiar with smtplib

Answer (score 1):

assuming the last line of your code returns 'in stock'

```
condition=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='availability']//span[contains(text(),'In stock.')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")

if condition == 'in stock':
    # logic to add to cart
else:
    pass
```

for the logic on adding an item/interacting with buttons look into this : https://pythonspot.com/selenium-click-button/

Comment: I tried the code but it doesn't seem to add to cart. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. I've added it on the main question part if you would like to try it.

Comment: @DavidCopperfield try removing the try except blocks for now to identify the error, after youve resolved the issue, add them back